# Extending ZfcUsers UserController

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

i want to extend the `UserController` with an `setEventManager` implementation, to display another layout - just with an login mask.

When i call the url `www.example.com` i get my Controller, with the other layout. 
But if type in a wrong username, i redirected `to www.exmpale.com/user/login` and i get the default layout.

How i can overwrite all routes from `ZfcUser Module` and redirect them to my own controller, to ensure, the `UserController` can not called directly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you probably just have to edit the file `module.config.php`. It contains all [route definitions](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/config/module.config.php).

From how I understand your question you have an own controller called something like `MyBetterUserController`?

You can add an own module as extension to the `ZfcUser` module, maybe you want to call it something like `ZfcUserMod`. This new module will only contain a `Module.php` file and a folder `config` with the configuration file.

Then you can define your routes in this **module’s configuration file** and overwrite all routes from `ZfcUser`. Make sure that you use the exactly same route names (the keys in the array) as `ZfcUser` does (currently they use **zfcuser** as route name). Otherwise the routes will not be overwriten and the UrlHelper will not use your routes.

Then add `ZfcUserMod` to the global `application.config.php` **after** `ZfcUser`.

Comment: Yes, you understand my question right.
But i tried to avoid changing the original source files of the module (update compatibility) 
I also tried to overwrite the routes in my own module.config.php. But this changes take no effect.

Comment: I think I once had a problem with overwriting routes that might help you. You either have to declare it in a module **before** or **afterwards** (don’t know if you can overwrite them or if already defined routes are not overwriten; I think the first defined route is always used). So you could create a module `KFOZfcUser` and set it in your `application.ini.php` directly before (or after) the real `ZfcUser` module. You have to give your new routes the same names as the ones in `ZfcUser` (i.e. `zfcuser` with the child routes `login` etc.).

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution. If i load my Module **after** all other Modules, i can overwrite the settings. **application.config.php:**
`return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZfcBase',
        'ZfcUser',
        'BjyAuthorize',
        'KFOOnline',
    ),
    // ... more settings
);`
Please write your solution as answer, so i can mark it as solved.

Comment: I editted it. Does it really have to be after **all** other modules? I assume it’s enough if it’s after the section you want to overwrite? So I wrote it like this. If not, I will rewrite it as "after all other modules".

Comment: Its enough, when my Module is direct after the ZfcUser Module. But know i have all modules grouped in extern and own modules and maybe i have to overwrite another Setting - then i can just do it and have not to change the application.config.php again

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to override just the `controllers -> invocables pointing 'zfcuser'  => 'namespace\your\extendedusercontroller'` instead of rewriting all the routes ?